# Cannot connect to remote database from docker with java application

Tags: mysql, docker, java

Why my java application cannot connect to my mysql server ?

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  chiesulu:
    #image: 523840521829.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/djammadev/chiesulu:latest
    image: djammadev/chiesulu:latest
    ports:
      - 9030:80
    env_file:
      - setenv.env
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

volumes:
  db-data:
```

### setenv.env

```
EBEAN_DATASOURCE=db
DATABASE_USERNAME=mysql-user
DATABASE_PASSWORD=mysql-user-password
DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql-server.com/mydb?serverTimezone=UTC
DATABASE_DRIVER=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

### Error

```
chiesulu_1  | io.ebean.datasource.DataSourceInitialiseException: Error initialising DataSource with user: root url:jdbc:mysql://mysql-server.com/mydb?serverTimezone=UTC error:Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 10 times. Giving up.
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:250)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.datasource.pool.ConnectionPoolFactory.createPool(ConnectionPoolFactory.java:14)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.datasource.DataSourceFactory.create(DataSourceFactory.java:26)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InitDataSource.create(InitDataSource.java:121)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InitDataSource.createFromConfig(InitDataSource.java:116)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InitDataSource.initDataSource(InitDataSource.java:49)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InitDataSource.initialise(InitDataSource.java:34)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InitDataSource.init(InitDataSource.java:25)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.setDataSource(DefaultContainer.java:229)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:90)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:63)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:35)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.DatabaseFactory.create(DatabaseFactory.java:63)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.DbContext.getWithCreate(DbContext.java:105)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.DbContext.<init>(DbContext.java:44)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.DbContext.<clinit>(DbContext.java:24)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.DB.<clinit>(DB.java:65)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.Finder.db(Finder.java:123)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.Finder.byId(Finder.java:154)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.djammadev.chiesulu.resources.OwnershipResource.getConnected(OwnershipResource.java:41)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.djammadev.chiesulu.resources.OwnershipResource.getBaseKey(OwnershipResource.java:112)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.djammadev.chiesulu.resources.BandResource.getBaseKey(BandResource.java:51)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.shinitech.djammadev.resources.BasicResource.buildKey(BasicResource.java:343)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.shinitech.djammadev.resources.AbstractEntityResource.getAll(AbstractEntityResource.java:55)
chiesulu_1  |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
chiesulu_1  |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
chiesulu_1  |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
chiesulu_1  |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
chiesulu_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
chiesulu_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
chiesulu_1  |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
chiesulu_1  |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
chiesulu_1  | Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 10 times. Giving up.
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:897)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:447)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
chiesulu_1  |   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
chiesulu_1  |   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.createUnpooledConnection(ConnectionPool.java:543)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.createUnpooledConnection(ConnectionPool.java:538)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnectionForQueue(ConnectionPool.java:757)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.datasource.pool.PooledConnectionQueue.ensureMinimumConnections(PooledConnectionQueue.java:176)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.initialise(ConnectionPool.java:298)
chiesulu_1  |   at io.ebean.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:247)
chiesulu_1  |   ... 70 common frames omitted
chiesulu_1  | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
chiesulu_1  | 
chiesulu_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
chiesulu_1  |   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
chiesulu_1  |   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
chiesulu_1  |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
chiesulu_1  |   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:340)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:777)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:486)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1348)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:163)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:841)
chiesulu_1  |   ... 82 common frames omitted
chiesulu_1  | Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
chiesulu_1  |   at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:171)
chiesulu_1  |   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:103)
chiesulu_1  |   at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:220)
chiesulu_1  |   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:428)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:316)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
chiesulu_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:331)
chiesulu_1  |   ... 88 common frames omitted
chiesulu_1  | Oct 25, 2021 12:23:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
chiesulu_1  | SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ChiesuluApplication] in context with path [] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
```

Comment: What is the question here? If you are asking and answering your own question (which is perfectly allowable) then the solution should be posted as a answer, not included in the question.

Comment: You still need to describe the problem in the question sufficiently that somebody else would recognise it as matching theirs (e.g. include the error messages and how you configured the client), as it is there isn't enough here to help anybody else.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, As you can see I'm new.

Comment: Like this, your question looks much better. And welcome to serverfault.com!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by adding enabledTLSProtocols query parameter to the link of the mysql server.

As : `DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql-server.com/mydatabase?serverTimezone=UTC&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2`

The error was caused by an Exception :
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)`

This post helps me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332909/why-can-java-not-connect-to-mysql-5-7-after-the-latest-jdk-update-and-how-should